# Fluent Api en EF Core not working HasDefaultValueSql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this configuration in specific for table "customer", the field idCatalogTipoDoc, has the default value "1"

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
            {

                entity.Property(e => e.IdCatalogTipoDoc)
                    .HasColumnName("idCatalogTipoDoc")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("1");
           }

       }
```

Service

```
Customer customerReturn1 = new Customer()
                {
                  // Excluyo setear el campo idCatalogTipoDoc

               }
                await _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Add(customerReturn1);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It throws me an error of foreign key conflicts, because it is **not setting the default value** of the column, the operation is successful only when I set it when creating the entity. I should mention that I already added the default value in the bd sqlserver.

What can I be failing at? Maybe if I have not been as explicit as possible or I need to add information, correct me, thank you and I await your recommendations on my question

Comment: How are you adding an entity?

Comment: Can you post the related code about the Customer class and the related configuration for its properties? Whether the IdCatalogTipoDoc property is the foreign key? Besides, please explain more detail about "It throws me an error of foreign key conflicts, because it is not setting the default value of the column, the operation is successful only when I set it when creating the entity. ", do you mean when create new entity, if set value for the IdCatalogTipoDoc property, it is successful. But if not set value, it will display this error?